# CakePHP automatically filling a field with the value of another

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-keys, fullcalendar

I'm using Cake 2.3.1. 
In my Events/add view i have this field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', array('label' => 'Customer: '));
```

which is a input select form, which contains all my customers.
now **i need this:**

```
echo $this->Form->input('title', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

**to be automatically filled with the customer name i choose in the field above. 

how can this be done?**

Relations:

> Customer HasMany Events (foreign key -> customer_id)

Comment: Why do you want to set a field in the same form, which is just the value of a select option that you already know?

Comment: That's because the FullCalendar jquery needs a 'title' field, which is needed. i tried to edit it, and figured out that this is an easier solution.

Comment: You are better off asking how to achieve your end goal (e.g. how to use a select to populate the title of a new event, using x plugin), pointing out what you've tried, than to only ask about the solution you've chosen. There's likely a better way to do it.

Comment: before asking this question, i tried what you just adviced, but I was reprimanded, because of the too many questions in a single "ask", so i deleted that one and tried something simple. BTW I think you're right, but sometimes asking simple questions means getting an answer ;)

Comment: I asked a single question, but i guess it depends on interpretation of who reads.. I was explaining every solution i tried, trying to be as strict as possible.. I guess I should learn how to write here.. (as maybe in english since my vocabulary is very poor..)

Comment: You might find [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) a useful read; the key to a good question is to focus on your objective. Demonstrating yo'uve made an effort but without distracting from your goal, whatever that may be.

Comment: thanks! it's always a challenge to not being annoying while asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a very good idea to set a hidden value in a form that changes depending on a selection. Since an end-user can easily change it's value or may have Javascript disabled altogether (which would be required for on-the-fly changes), it's not trustworthy. It would be better to get the title upon saving the form in the beforeSave method of your Event model. For example:

```
function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['customer_id'])) {
        // Set the Customer.name field as Event.title
        $this->data[$this->alias]['title'] = $this->Customer->field(
            'name', array(
                // The condition for the find operation on this customer
                'id' => $this->data[$this->alias]['customer_id']
             )
        );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried, but after saving correctly I got 'Event.title' empty.

Comment: you forgot the check on `isset($this->data[$this->alias]['customer_id'])`

Comment: Ok, I managed to understand what's wrong. the cust_id is set, but when calling beforeSave(), it fails to do its job. the field i use as a source it's a VirtualField. may it interfere?

Comment: tried this last one. controller fails to call beforeSave(). the EventsController and Event model are in /plugin/FullCalendar., while Customer is in app/MVC. I read something about file path and extensions that must be set correctly.. (...this means I have no clue)

Comment: I tried to do this:
`function beforeSave($options = array()) {
     if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['customer_id'])) {
       $this->data[$this->alias]['title'] = 'I am a title';
     }
     return true;
}`

but my title field remains empty... but not null, since 'title' is required. I can't figure how to make this thing work.

Comment: ok... sorry.. it worked. i defined beforeSave outside the class.